# QuickCheck: why isn't there a function to pass a test and what to use instead?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, haskell-hedgehog

Why isn't there a `QuickCheck` function similar to `hedgehog`'s [`success`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.17/hedgehog-1.0.1/Hedgehog.html#v:success)? In particular I was wondering how one could translate a property like the following one:

```hs
prop_specialPair :: Property
prop_specialPair = property $ do
  (_, xs) <- forAll specialPair
  case xs of
    x:_ -> x /== 3
    _   -> success
```

In `QuickCheck` if I use [`=/=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:-61--47--61-) then I'm forced to return something of type `Property`, and there seem to be no constant function to return a passing property.

So I either have to resort to the `Bool` type:

```hs
prop_specialPair :: SpecialPair -> Bool
prop_specialPair SpecialPair { xs } =
  case xs of
    x:_ -> x == 3
    _   -> True
```

Or use a very awkward encoding for `success`, e.g.:

```hs
prop_specialPair :: SpecialPair -> Property
prop_specialPair SpecialPair { xs } =
  case xs of
    x:_ -> x =/= 3
    _   -> True === True
```

Are there better ways to express the property above in `QuickCheck`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `property` function from the `Testable` class, and various `Testable` instances to create a `Property` with whatever characteristics you need.

For example, `property ()` always succeeds. For another example, `property (b :: Bool)` succeeds iff `b == True`.

So you could do this for example:

```
prop_specialPair :: SpecialPair -> Property
prop_specialPair SpecialPair { xs } =
  case xs of
    x:_ -> x =/= 3
    _   -> property ()
```

Or you can make it more explicit by using the `Testable Result` instance and the value `succeeded :: Result`:

```
prop_specialPair :: SpecialPair -> Property
prop_specialPair SpecialPair { xs } =
  case xs of
    x:_ -> x =/= 3
    _   -> property succeeded
```

Comment: A couple of weeks later I realize I should have also asked about how to mark a property as failing ...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use implication with [`(==>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:-61--61--62-):

```hs
prop_specialPair :: Property
prop_specialPair =
  forAll specialPair $ \(_, xs) ->
    not (null xs) ==> take 1 xs =/= [3]
```